# Interpret Crash debug log from Android Vitals (Play Console)

Tags: android, crash-reports

On my first android app I got this Crash debug log report (blocks) from Play Console (Android Vitals) and I need interpret it:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:    
at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(CursorWindow.java)
1. at android.database.CursorWindow.getString (CursorWindow.java:439)
2. at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString (AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
3.  at ms.util.xTab.setSelect (xTab.java)
    or               .RegistrosIniciales (xTab.java)
    or               .Insert (xTab.java)
    or               .SacaWh (xTab.java)
    or               .SacaP (xTab.java)
    or               .CaODefault (xTab.java)
    or               .Field (xTab.java)
    or               .valTablaNoVacia (xTab.java)
4.  at ms.util.xFrag.onAttach (xFrag.java)
    or                .onDetach (xFrag.java)
    or                .onCreateView (xFrag.java)
    or                .CreaCView (xFrag.java)
    or                .LlenaAC (xFrag.java)
    or                .DatValMSG (xFrag.java)
    or                .ActDesViews (xFrag.java)
    or                .UpdateG (xFrag.java)
    or                .CampoSinAlias (xFrag.java)
    or                .access$000 (xFrag.java)
5.  at ms.util.xFrag.BotSav (xFrag.java)
6.  at ms.simcall.Fragment_Dats.SavDet (Fragment_Dats.java)
```

Comparing with usual Android Monitor log of Android Studio, I have problem with debug this.  For example, no line number on my top code of stack:

```
at ms.util.xTab.setSelect (xTab.java)
```

Also not understanding the lines prefixed with "or". What is the meaning ? :

```
**at** ms.util.xTab.setSelect (xTab.java)
**or**               .RegistrosIniciales (xTab.java)
**or**               .Insert (xTab.java)"
```

Finally, what are the initial numbers (1., 2., 3.) in "at" lines? Are they threads? Stack order? Is the stack order shown the same as Android Monitor log?

I've been reading the Play Console docs about this but not success with this details.

Answer (score 1):

After hours trying to understand this, what I have discovered so far is this log is shown that way because of obfuscation of Proguard.
The prefixes "OR" are because Proguard renames several methods with the same letter (something strange to be of the same class), therefore it cannot establish the specific method that generated the exception. Anyway, although you can, it's very difficult to debug.
Unless I'm wrong setting up the Proguard.